# add_query_arg() and empty variables inside

Tags: query, links

I have link:

```
<a href="'.esc_url(add_query_arg(array('search' => $search, 'category' => $category, 'filter' => $filter), '/site')).'">Click</a>
```

And some variables sometimes exist and sometimes don't, like $filter, which sometimes does not exist. Now I would like the variable does not exist, that it would not appear in the link, because the debugger displays the Notice "Undefined variable".

How should it be coded correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your array before-hand, optionally populate it, and pass it to the `add_query_arg()` function like so:

```
$url_query_args = array();

if( isset( $search ) ) {
    $url_query_args['search'] = $search;
}

if( isset( $category ) ) {
    $url_query_args['category'] = $category;
}

if( isset( $filter ) ) {
    $url_query_args['filter'] = $filter;
}

esc_url( add_query_arg( $url_query_args, '/site' ) );
```

Or you could loop through an array of possible query args:

```
$url_query_args = array();
$possible_args  = array(
    'search',
    'category',
    'filter',
);

foreach( $possible_args as $arg ) {

    if( ! isset( ${$arg} ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $url_query_args[ $arg ] = ${$arg};

}

esc_url( add_query_arg( $url_query_args, '/site' ) );
```